Unable to pass valid graphQL request body inside data dog API test
I am building multi-step api test in data dog by passing graphQL request to fetch data from source. I am passing below graphQL request body w/ variables but it seems this data dog is unable to parse this request. PAGESIZE is local variable that holds data type of int
query Organizations($pageSize: Int) {
   organizations(pageSize: $pageSize) {
    count
    items {
      id
    }
  }
}

{
  "pageSize" {{ PAGESIZE }}
}

As you can see in the attached screenshot, the variable section is considered to be invalid and shows red validation error. So far I have tried following formats in variable section but all shows validation errors
"pageSize": {{PAGESIZE}}
"pageSize": 10
pageSize: {{PAGESIZE}}
pageSize:10
What is working?
When I remove the variable section from the graphQL request, the request successfully returns all results but I want to return 10 records not all of them.
Does anyone knows what is the reason behind this error and how do I fix it?

Have you tried without the quotation ?
{
pageSize: {{ PAGESIZE }}
}

@Leaderfrank - I did. I just added that to the list in my original question of what did not work. Thanks for pointing that out. It throws same parsing error

This is what solved the problem for me. Changing the Body Type in request body to application/json and converting the body to JSON type. I can use local and global variables as well in the request body
{
  "query": "query Organizations($pageSize: Int) { organizations(pageSize: $pageSize) { count items { id } }}",
  "variables": {
    "pageSize": {{ PAGESIZE }}
  }
}

You have to convert graphQL query to a JSON body. I used this converter graphQL to JSON and it worked:

https://datafetcher.com/graphql-json-body-converter


Don't know about datadog, but in an ordinary request body you'ld declare the variables like this variables: { pageSize: ... }. In the same manner, the query would have a query key: query: {query Organizations(...) {...} } - "query" has mutliple meanings in GraphQL, the inner query just denotes just that it isn't a mutation or subscription, the outer that it's the general query part of the request and not, for example, the variables or the operationName part.
Also, have a closer look at the error message. It doesn't even complain about PAGESIZE, but about the key, "pageSize". So the error cannot be solved by attempting different alternatives for {{ PAGESIZE }}.
As I said, I've no knowledge about datadog, but an ordinary request body might look like this:
{
  "query": "query Organizations(...) {...}",
  "variables": {
    "pageSize": ...
  }
}

I assume that the {{ ... }} is for variable insertion done by datadog - otherwise {{ PAGESIZE}} is also wrong, of course, because it's no proper JSON syntax.

I tried your format but data dog does not like it.
inline {   "query": 'query Organizations {   organizations {     count     items {       id     }   } }',  "variables": {    "pageSize": {{ PAGESIZE }} } }
I got below error
{"errors":[{"message":"Syntax Error: Expected Name, found String "query".","locations":[{"line":2,"column":3}],"extensions":{"code":"GRAPHQL_PARSE_FAILED"}}]}

@vormier can you try to remove the quotes from "query", "variables" and "pageSize"? Maybe datadog doesn't want the JSON style but the JavaScript Object style, i.e. unquoted keys ...
